# Angular: How To Use Default Input Required Validation

Tags: angular

So I just want to use the default `required` validation from HTML.

This is my code:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <div class="login-container">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input
        required
        type="email"
        [(ngModel)]="vm.email"
        placeholder="Email"
        name="Email"
      ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input
        required
        type="password"
        [(ngModel)]="vm.password"
        placeholder="Password"
        name="Password"
      ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <div class="ion-text-center">
      <ion-button expand="full" class="button-round" type="submit"
        >Login</ion-button
      >
    </div>
  </div>
```

If I click the submit button, it will go to the `submit()` function. In React, if the inputs are not valid, by default, it will prevent the action to the `submit()` function and also prompt an error message saying `This field is required` (or something like that). How can I do it in Angular? I have searched for the solution, and apparently, they are suggesting doing custom validation (which is a hassle). I just want to make it simple. My validation is only `required`.

Comment: In Angular you need to use a reactive form to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically by default angular is adding something called novalidate. If you guys want to use browser's native form validation just add ngNativeValidate attribute:

```
<form ngNativeValidate></form>
```